# Analyticity of $\frac{z}{\bar z +2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't seem to find a way to express $$f(z)=\frac{z}{\bar z +2}$$
as $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ so that I can check the Cauchy-Riemann equations. There must be some really simple idea to prove that $f(z)$ is not analytic anywhere but I'm stuck. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ was analytic, $g(z) = \frac z {f(z)}-2 = \overline z$ would also be analytic when $z \neq 0,-2$.

Comment: yes. If you haven't you should show that $z \mapsto 1/z$ is analytic (with Cauchy Riemann equations). Then the rest follow because the composition of two analytic functions is still analytic.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(\bar{z}+2)(z+2)=|z+2|^2$.
Hence, for $z=x+iy\not=-2$,
$$\frac{z}{\bar z +2}=\frac{z(z+2)}{|z+2|^2}=\frac{(x+iy)(x+2+iy)}{(x+2)^2+y^2}.$$
Now it is easy to find the real part $u(x,y)$ and the imaginery part $v(x,y)$.

P.S. However, in order to check if $f$ is analytic there is a shorter way: see mercio's answer.